# Migrating from artifactory 5.8.4 on RHEL7 to artifactory 7.41.4 on RHEL8 using external Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, database-migration, artifactory, multiple-versions

We are trying to practice the migration before the real one.  Therefore, we made copies of the existing servers (art and db) and placed them in our sandbox.
Then stood up 2 RHEL8 servers, installing Oracle on newdb and Artifactory on newart
Exported database and schema from olddb and imported it into newdb.
Modified the system.yaml to point to newdb and use the existing dbuser and password for artifactory.
Copied the master.key from etc/security on oldart to same location on newart
Copied the license file from etc on oldart to the same location on newart
Installed the oracle client, copied over ojdbc8.jar, libociicus.so, and libiciei.so from the oracle client installation to bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib

We did a 
`chown -R artuser:artgroup /opt/jfrog and for /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var`

When starting up the newart server, we get a 500 error when going to newart:8081/artifactory

When checking the console.log after restarting, the first error I find is:

```
[DEBUG] Cluster join: Pinging service registry on 'http://localhost:8046'
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] running retry attempt #1
[DEBUG] Cluster join: Retry 1: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Failed to ping access, response status: 404 Not Found (returned 404)
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] operation attempt #1 failed. retrying in 1s. current error: Failed to ping access, response status: 404 Not Found (returned 404)
```

I don't know what this is but suspect it has something to do with this earlier message:
`Missing required services: [jfrt jfac jffe jfob]`

We are not using HA so I'm a little confused by the "Cluster join:" messages.

Verified that the system.yaml has `haEnabled: false`, and checked the logs to see that it found it.
Logged into the db directly with the dbuser in system.yaml and it works.  When I put in a bad password we get a 404 error on 8081 anyway, not the 500 error.

I'm not sure how to proceed.  I can revert newdb and newart to snapshots taken before we began the artifactory install and before we did the database import on oracle.

Should I complete the install and configuration of newart before importing the data from olddb into newdb?

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the upgrade steps from this [JFrog Doc](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/upgrade)? Upgrading from 5.x to 7.x will likely cause issues. The upgrade path would be 5.8.4 -> any 6.x version above 6.10.x -> to any 7.x version.

That document also has guidance on things to consider before upgrading, like new system requirements in 7.x. For example, 7.x uses port 8082 for the UI (and most external inbound transactions) and port 8081 only provides headless access to the Artifactory micro service.

Comment: RTFM, right.  Thank you.  I don't know how I missed that but I'll give that a try and see if we have more success.